# Google Authorship image of my Blogspot blog has disappeared from the Google SERPs

Tags: search-results, google-authorship

I have a Blogspot blog and my images used to appear on the Google SERPs for my keywords using Google Authorship Markup.  My image was shown for last 2 months but while checking SERP for my blog, I found that my authorship markup is not working anymore. My image, name and G+ followers count is not appearing near my Blogspot URL in SERPs.

I didn't made any changes in my Google+ profile or in my Blogspot header tag where I had put the authorship code.

Answer (score 1):

Without coding!! [**Simply  Use this method to link your content to your Google+ profile**](https://plus.google.com/authorship) (authorship - via email).